# How can I increase the number of concurrent async calls?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to increase the number of concurrent async calls I can make in C#. Specifically, I am trying to match the performance I'm seeing in Node.js.

Below are two sample programs, one in C# and one in JavaScript. The both read a random number of bytes into a buffer from a 10MB file containing random numbers, then execute this operation 2000 times asynchronously. The JavaScript program can do this about 60,000 times per second on my machine, but the C# program can only do about 3,000. As far as I can tell, they are doing the same thing, but I realize there are definitely some differences.

I have run similar tests with different functions, including sleeping for a small amount of time, and performing inserts to a Cassandra cluster using the Datastax Cassandra drivers. The latter functionality is what I'm really trying to improve, as I can only get about 80 inserts per second in C#, but about 5000 in Node.

Can someone help me explain this discrepancy?

```
// C#

class Program
{
    static Random r = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int iterations = 2000;

        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, iterations).Select(i => ReadFile()).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        s.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Total elapsed milliseconds was {0}.", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Total iterations were {0}.", iterations);
        Console.WriteLine("Total iterations per second was {0}.", iterations / s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }

    static async Task ReadFile()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Temp\random.txt";
        int readSize = r.Next(512, 10 * 1024);

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            await reader.ReadAsync(new char[readSize], 0, readSize);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// JavaScript

var fs = require('fs');
var now = require('performance-now');

var iterations = 2000;
var startTime = now();
var runningIterations = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) {
    readFile(function () {
        runningIterations++;

        if (iterations == runningIterations) {
            totalTime = (now() - startTime);
            console.log("Total iterations: " + iterations);
            console.log("Total time: " + totalTime);
            console.log("Iterations per second: " + (iterations / (totalTime / 1000)));
        }
    });
}

function readFile(callback) {
    var path = "/Temp/random.txt";

    fs.open(path, 'r', function (err, fd) {
        var readSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 * 1024) + 512;
        var buffer = new Buffer(readSize);
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, readSize, 0, function (err, bytesRead, buffer) {
            callback();
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why so I can improve the question.

Comment: Slight performance gain using `Parallel.For(...)` over building up a collection with `Enumerable` and awaiting `Task.WaitAll`. (I achieved ~5134.15 it/sec)

Comment: @BradChristie I see the same improvement—about 5,000-6,000 iterations per second. It's still far below the 60,000-70,000 that I get with Node. Unfortunately, `Parallel.For` doesn't seem to improve my Cassandra calls (which is actually part of the reason I moved to `Task.WaitAll` originally).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I believe C# is slower, given the following:

Running your node script, I receive:

```
Total iterations: 2000
Total time: 1199.8234639999998
Iterations per second: 1666.9118916314178
```

Running your C# script, as-is, I receive:

```
Total elapsed milliseconds was 1041.
Total iterations were 2000.
Total iterations per second was 1920.61576477911.
```

If I refactor it to use `Parallel.For`:

```
static Random r = new Random();

void Main()
{
     int iterations = 2000;

    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    Parallel.For(0, iterations, ReadFile);

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Total elapsed milliseconds was {0}.", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Total iterations were {0}.", iterations);
    Console.WriteLine("Total iterations per second was {0}.", iterations / s.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
static async void ReadFile(int x)
{
    string path = @"C:\Temp\random.txt";
    int readSize = r.Next(512, 10 * 1024);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        await reader.ReadAsync(new char[readSize], 0, readSize);
    }
}
```

I receive a pretty substantial performance gain:

```
Total elapsed milliseconds was 389.
Total iterations were 2000.
Total iterations per second was 5134.14889288497.
```

I'm also betting if I cached the buffer, in all scenarios, there would be another substantial bump. But, I can only go by performance on my local machine. And, from what I see, there's nothing that makes me think "oh wow, something is way off". I also don't know your environment. :shrug:

Comment: Interesting. Your results are more what I expected to see. Obviously environment will dictate much of the outcome, but I can't explain such a huge disparity on my machine.

Comment: Actually, trying it on another machine, I see large drops in the Node version, which are mirrored in my Cassandra tests. The second machine is a VM with two cores whereas my desktop has 8 cores. The C# performance is the same between the two machines though.

Comment: Is there a level of caching?  There is a fs available that caches, maybe that's the benefactor?

Comment: Interesting that the Parallel.For version is so much faster. Is this a consequence of its limiting the number of concurrent requests, reducing the memory pressure and reducing contention on the kernel (less simultaneous async I/O operations)?

Comment: @Brandon: the parallel library uses a [partitioner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.aspx) which can dramatically reduce overhead (whereas executing tasks yourself is a 1:1 ratio). The partitioner essentially groups units of work making more effective use of resources (especially across multiple small units of work).